# How to read/write external data resource from within runnable JAR?

Tags: java, command-line, jar, resources

I'd like to run `MyRunnableJar.jar` from command line. It will need to read from `file_[1-4].dat`, do some processing and then write to `file_5.dat`. All of the aforementioned data files are near `MyRunnableJar.jar` in the file system. For example:

- `super_directory/`

  - `MyRunnableJar.jar`
  - `data_resources/`

    - `file_1.dat`
    - `file_2.dat`
    - `file_3.dat`
    - `nested_data_directory/`

      - `file_4.dat`
      - `file_5.dat`

(`MyRunnableJar.jar` was created by Eclipse's `Export` feature.)

The reason I want to do things this way is because the application is too computationally expensive to run on my little laptop. Instead, I want to put it on a remote server (with all the big data files that it has to access) and run it there.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to show the runnable JAR where those data files are. The data files can certainly be moved around if need be. However, keeping them inside the JAR is not an option, because if I want to change even a bit of the application code, I'd have to re-transfer the entire JAR, which would be quite large if it includes the data files. Moreover, I would be unable to write to `file_5.dat` if it was actually in my JAR.

I am aware that there are many questions similar to this on Stack Exchange, but in each case the question is slightly different in some important way.

---

EDIT:

- Please see Accepted Answer.
- Also note that Andre's solution (explained in the comment) also worked, since in my case, the JAR and the data file will always be in the same position in the filesystem relative to one another.

Comment: _Why_ is each question different in some important way?  Show effort.

Comment: I'm not quite sure but I think if you use a relative path in a java program it starts in the working directory. So if you say `new File("data_resources/file_1.dat")` it should open the first file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really need to be able to do is figure out what directory your `.jar` file is in regardless of what the `System.property("user.dir");` returns or where the `MyRunnableJar.jar` is executed from. You don't want to have to assume that you are currently in the same directory as `MyRunnableJar.jar`, if you aren't you can't calculate the *relative* directory because you don't know where you are *relative* to that `.jar` anymore.

The following code snippet will do this for you:

```
return new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
```

<sub>replace `MyClass` with your `main` class</sub>

Then you can use that to build the path to the directory you want to read from. The is all cake from there.

Comment: Just to be clear:
The return value of your snippet is the File object associated with the class the snippet is run from, correct?
In that case, the next step is to copy and manipulate the path for that class File so it actually points to the resource I want to open for reading/writing?

PS: Andre's simple `new File("relative_path/file_name.fil")` solution worked for me. Is there any reason to prefer the solution you propose instead?

Comment: yes, my solution will work regardless where the `.jar` is located and regardless where it is executed from. If you execute the `.jar` from a path that is *not* where it is located ( ie; the current dir is **not** the same as location of the `.jar`, that solution will not work.